# Image list using ng-repeat change opacity of visible item

Tags: html, css, angularjs

In my application I am displaying one list with images in it using `ng-repeat`.

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|   |           Previous Image 0         |    |
|   +------------------------------------+    |
|   +------------------------------------+    |
|   |                                    |    |
|   |            Current Image 1         |    |
|   |                                    |    |
|   +------------------------------------+    |
|   +----------------------------------- +    |
|   |             Next Image 2           |    |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

Code to display this list is as below:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myImageArray">
   <img ng-src="{{item.url}}" id="image{{item.id}}">
</div>
```

**What I want to achieve:**
In the list I want to set the opacity of `Previous Image 0` and `Next Image 2` to `50%`.
And opacity of `Current Image 1` to `100%`.

Basically the image that is visible should have opacity of `100%` and rest of the images should have opacity of `50%`.

Comment: Will you have only 3 images in your `ng-repeat`?

Comment: No there can be more than 3 images in the list.

Comment: So you can have 10 images for example. How do you decide which one is the current image?

Comment: Yes we can have 10 images, I don't know how to find which is visible.

Comment: This should be simple, but I need to understand first how you differentiate the "current" image from all the rest.

Comment: The images list should looks like vertical carousel?

Comment: Yes it should be vertical carousel, and also it is hard to find which item is currently visible. can we use anchors in this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following function to identify whether element is fully visible in viewport.

```
 function elementInViewport(el) {
  var top = el.offsetTop;
  var left = el.offsetLeft;
  var width = el.offsetWidth;
  var height = el.offsetHeight;

  while(el.offsetParent) {
    el = el.offsetParent;
    top += el.offsetTop;
    left += el.offsetLeft;
  }

  return (
    top >= window.pageYOffset &&
    left >= window.pageXOffset &&
    (top + height) <= (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight) &&
    (left + width) <= (window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth)
  );
}
```

On the basis of that you can write some directive to decide which is current element you are viewing and depending on that you can decide opacity for that element using ng-style or ng-class.

I know this is not a straight forward solution but I think this is one way you can get which element is your current element in your view port.